# Formatting Names for Documents

Tags: python, formatting

I am trying to format names being input by users to output.
Ex. If input is John Smith Doe then output is Doe, J.S.
Ex.#2 If input is Jane Doe then output is Doe, J.
As experienced coders can observe I am getting an index error once the input is under [2], I am having trouble figuring out how to achieve the 2nd output and so on.

```
user_name = input()
user_tokens = user_name.split()
last_name = user_tokens[2]
first_name = user_tokens[0]
middle_last_name = user_tokens[1]

if user_tokens[2] in last_name:
    print('{}, {}.{}.'.format(last_name, first_name[0], middle_last_name[0]))
else:
    print('{], {}.'.format(middle_last_name, first_name[0]))
```

Comment: Nevertheless always show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're asking (please read [ask]), but your second string has a typo: `{]` should be `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grabbing the third element of the `split()` call, you could grab the last element with `last_name = user_tokens[:-1]`.

```
user_name = input()
user_tokens = user_name.split()
last_name = user_tokens[:-1]
first_name = user_tokens[0]
middle_last_name = user_tokens[1]

if user_tokens[:-1] in last_name:
    print('{}, {}.{}.'.format(last_name, first_name[0], middle_last_name[0]))
else:
    print('{}, {}.'.format(middle_last_name, first_name[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use it like this?

```
user_name = input()
user_tokens = user_name.split()

if len(user_tokens) == 3:
  last_name = user_tokens[2]
  first_name = user_tokens[0]
  middle_last_name = user_tokens[1]
  print('{}, {}.{}.'.format(last_name, first_name[0], middle_last_name[0]))
else:
  last_name = user_tokens[1]
  first_name = user_tokens[0]
  print('{}, {}.'.format(middle_last_name, first_name[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the list before you trying to access the items in it. For example:

```py
if len(user_tokens) == 3:
    last_name = user_tokens[2]
```

But with negative indexes you get the items counted from the end instead so `user_tokens[-1]` will always give you the last name.

Using colon syntax you can get a chunk from the list. `a_list[start:end]` returns items from index `start` to `end-1` in a new list. If you leave out `start` it will get items from index 0. If you leave out `end` it will get all remaining items in the list.

You can also combine negative indexes with the colon.

Read more abot it in the documantation for [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

```py
input_name = input()
names = input_name.split()
initials = ''.join(f' {a[0]}.' for a in names[:-1])
print(names[-1] + ',' + initials)
```